# Haskell Stack build specific executable

Tags: haskell, build, binary, executable, haskell-stack

How to build an specific stack executable file, ie. those specified in `projectname.cabal`, like:

```
executable executable-name
  hs-source-dirs:      tools
  main-is:             ExecutableModule.hs
  ghc-options:         -Wall -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , hsass
                     , hlibsass
```

I would need to compile `executable-name` and no other. It would be something like:

```
stack build --executable executable-name
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack [uses a component based lookup](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command/#target-syntax), e.g.

```
stack build packagename:component-type:component-name
```

So if your package is called "foo", and your executable is called "bar", you can use

```
stack build foo:exe:bar
```

However, if the component-name is unique, you can drop the package's name and the component type. So if your executable is called "exectuable-name", it's

```
stack build :executable-name
```

Comment: This ability seems to be lost from Nov 2015, up to now. (ref. [commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1406](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1406))

Comment: The precises syntax for a component based lookup is also documented here: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command/#target-syntax