# How to make Stack only build one executable? stack build :exe1 doesn't work?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have multiple executables in one of my Stack projects:

```
executable m1
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main1.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5

executable m2
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  main-is:             Main2.hs
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
```

I would like to build only one of them at a time. From the [documentation](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command/) and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137310/haskell-stack-build-specific-executable), it would seem that the following command should work:

```
stack build :m2
```

*but* what actually happens is that both executables, m1 and m2, are always built regardless of whether I include the package name, the package type, etc.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried `project:m1` or `project:exe:m1`?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Yes. All variations of the target end up building all executables. I wonder if its a bug. The version of Stack I'm using is Version 1.1.0 x86_64 hpack-0.13.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell Stack build specific executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137310/haskell-stack-build-specific-executable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment. See https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1406

Comment: This seems to be possible again now, per the issue as of August 25th 2017.